# NGINX rewrite rules for multisite

Tags: php, multisite, nginx, uploads

I have a WordPress 4.6 network running on an Ubuntu 16.04 server with [NGINX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx).

I have one main site and then I migrated a single site installation to a subsite under that main site. I made all the DB changes, URL changes, copied over all the themes and plugins, and copied all the uploads to `wp-content/uploads/sites/2` with `2` being the site ID.

When I go to view the site everything looks fine except the images do not display. when I click on the image, the path indicates that its looking for the image in the `wp-content/uploads` folder instead of the `wp-content/uploads/sites/2` folder.  Would this be an issue with the rewrite rules? If so, how would I go about fixing it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17888/nginx-wordpress-multisite-rewrite-rules?rq=1) first, maybe the answer on there helps you already out. Look alse here on the right, below the **Related** for possible answers.